# error coding (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Tags: vb.net

i have this problem"error coding (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)" please help  me and  this my full coding.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim Command As MySqlCommand
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
        Dim Sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Try
            If Button1.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                Me.Button1.BackColor = Color.Lime
            End If
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from info.penjara"
            query = "update penjara.info set keadaan =1 where no =1 "
            Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

            Dim spath As String
            Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer

            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            If Button1.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                mysound.PlayLooping()
            End If
            Form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
        Dim Sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Try
            If Button2.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                Me.Button2.BackColor = Color.Lime
            End If
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from info.penjara"
            query = "update penjara.info set keadaan =1 where no =2 "

            Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

            Dim spath As String
            Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer

            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            If Button2.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                mysound.PlayLooping()
            End If
            Form3.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
        Dim Sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Try
            If Button3.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                Me.Button3.BackColor = Color.Lime
            End If
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from info.penjara"
            query = "update penjara.info set keadaan =1 where no =3 "
            Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

            Dim spath As String
            Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer

            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            If Button3.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                mysound.PlayLooping()
            End If
            Form4.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
        Dim Sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Try
            If Button4.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                Me.Button4.BackColor = Color.Lime
            End If
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from info.penjara"
            query = "update penjara.info set keadaan =1 where no =4 "
            Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

            Dim spath As String
            Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer

            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            If Button4.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                mysound.PlayLooping()
            End If
            Form5.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
        Dim Sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
        Try
            If Button5.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                Me.Button5.BackColor = Color.Lime
            End If
            MysqlConn.Open()
            Dim query As String
            query = "select * from info.penjara"
            query = "update penjara.info set keadaan =1 where no =5 "
            Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader()
            MysqlConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            MysqlConn.Dispose()

            Dim spath As String
            Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer

            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            If Button5.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                mysound.PlayLooping()
            End If
            Form6.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim query As String
        Dim spath As String
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader


        query = "Select * from penjara.info"
        Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            Try
                Reader.Close()
                count = count + 1
                query = "Select penjara.info where  no = '" & count & "'"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Catch ex As Exception


                If (rdr.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (rdr.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
                    Form2.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                    spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
                    mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
                    mysound.PlayLooping()
                ElseIf (rdr.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (rdr.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
                    Form3.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                    spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
                    mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
                    mysound.PlayLooping()
                ElseIf (rdr.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (rdr.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
                    Form4.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                    spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
                    mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
                    mysound.PlayLooping()
                ElseIf (rdr.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (rdr.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
                    Form5.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                    spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
                    mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
                    mysound.PlayLooping()
                ElseIf (rdr.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (rdr.GetInt32("no") = count) Then
                    Form5.Show()
                    Me.Hide()
                    spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
                    mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
                    mysound.PlayLooping()
                End If
            End Try
        End While
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: no one will inspect your whole block of code unless or maybe when you tell which line thrown the error. :p

Comment: haha lol.... the error at line "If (rdr.GetInt32("keadaan") = 1) & (rdr.GetInt32("no") = count) Then"

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `rdr` object is `Nothing` and in your `If` statements, your `&` should be `AndAlso`

Comment: and your **IF ELSE** checking against the same condition?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error-causing line is in a `Catch` block and `rdr` is only set in the accompanying `Try`, there's no guarantee that `rdr` is ever initialized. Since the data schema is not using English (I think?), I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish with the handler. I recommend doing an `If rdr Is Nothing` and doing a separate error type for that before going into what you currently have in the `Catch` block.

And, as people pointed out in the comments, use the `And` operator (or `AndAlso` to replicate C# behavior) instead of `&`, which is the string concatenator in VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Look what you have going on here:

```
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

MysqlConn.Open()

Dim query As String
Dim spath As String
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader

query = "Select * from penjara.info"
Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
While Reader.Read
    Try
        Reader.Close()
        count = count + 1
        query = "Select penjara.info where  no = '" & count & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

You've got 2 readers: `Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader` and `Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader`.

You do `Reader = Command.ExecuteReader` and a `While Reader.Read` **and then immediately close it via `Reader.Close()`**.  That's problem 1.  Problem 1a is that you are even looping through that first Reader.  Why? You aren't doing anything with it?

Problem 2 is that your second Reader you do `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader` yet you don't do anything with it.  It seems to me that your `If` statement wasn't supposed to be inside of the `Catch` but underneath the `rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader`.  Therefore, move your `Catch` down *after* the `If` statement where you are using the `rdr` object.

Problem 3 is your `&` inside the `If` statement.  Those need to be changed to `AndAlso`.

Here is how I tried to salvage things:

```
Try

    count = count + 1
    query = "Select penjara.info where  no = '" & count & "'"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    While rdr.Read

        Dim keadaan = rdr.GetInt32("keadaan")
        Dim no = rdr.GetInt32("no")

        If keadaan = 1 AndAlso no = count Then

            Form2.Show()
            Me.Hide()
            spath = "C:\Users\User\Music\emergency003.wav"
            mysound = New Media.SoundPlayer(spath)
            mysound.PlayLooping()

        ElseIf 'insert all the other conditions here ...

        End If

    End While

Catch ex As Exception

    'TODO: Handle exception.

End Try
```

Comment: yeah. Lots of problems :)

Comment: can you help me to resolve the problem?im a beginner programmer. :(

Comment: @jibal - I am really just unsure about what you are trying to do here.  Your `If` statement I'm guessing wasn't totally finished? It's like you copied your condition and code blocks all the way down and only changed the `Form` number.  I'm guessing you meant to increment the `spath` maybe, or the `keadaan` condition?  You tell me.  What is it that you are trying to do with that `If` statement?

Comment: @CodeMaverick- let me explain about my if else statement .. ok i want display with other form. the form will change if keadaan =1 wil open other form if keadaan=0 will stay in form 1 from database.

Comment: @jibal - So what about `no = count`?

Comment: what is the need for AndAlso in `If keadaan = 1 AndAlso no = count Then`, AND is enough na? may i know what is the difference between AndAlso & AND(Logical AND)

Comment: @CodeMaverick- count use for procced next row in database..

Comment: @SujithKarivelil - `And` evaluates both sides of the condition, whereas `AndAlso` is a short-circuit and only evaluates the right side if the left side is true.  Same is true for `Or` and `OrElse`.

Comment: @SujithKarivelil my if else are wrong?

Comment: @ jibal : it gives the correct result but am not sure about the explanation.

Comment: the correct way to use AndAlso operator is  :                                                            `Dim a, b As Integer`
        `a = 1`
        `b = 1`
        `If b AndAlso a = 1 Then`
            `MsgBox("If loop is correct")`
        `End If`

Comment: @SujithKarivelil - yeah  but my if..else still not working

Comment: thanks guys now my program almost done.the problem are solve ...#freeGaza